# Replaced GFCI twice

Tags: electrical

I replaced the GFCI outlet, have electric from breaker box to GFCI.
GFCI doesn't work. Replaced GFCI thinking it was the problem.
Still not working, so I got a regular socket put in and it works.
What is the problem? I need the GFCI as this goes to my bathrooms
and to the garage outlets. I know the GFCI is connected correctly.
I test hot wire 
Thank you

Comment: Have you tested the receptacles in this circuit with a plug-in tester to see if the basic function is correct? Are you using a GFCI breaker in the panel or a receptacle? It is possible that this particular circuit has a leak to ground which is tripping the GFCI device. The next thing to go would be to take the GFCI device that didn't work in this circuit and put it in another circuit to see if it works there.

Comment: When you turn off the power to a circuit and then turn it back on, I gather that some GFCI receptacles need to be reset.

Comment: Is the GFCI trying to feed any downstream loads from its LOAD terminals?

Comment: Are you connecting to the GFCI outlet's LOAD terminals? You must connect to the LINE terminals.

Comment: I am connecting the black hot to the line the married white to the line, and the neutral black and white to load end of outlet

Answer (score 1):

What DoxyLover said.

Verify that the power wires coming from the panel go to the "Line" terminals and the wires feeding the other receptacles go to the "Load" terminals. They are NOT interchangeable and the GFCI will not work if it is backfed.

Comment: I have the hot black wire to the line and the married white to the line. Then connected the neutral black to lead and it's married white to load, then the ground wire.  So why does a regular socket in this spot but not a GFIC?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Found the problem, it was the hot wire was loose in the breaker box. Got the wire tightened and now we working great.